# Running ghc fails with message about iOS simulator

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform

I tried running `ghc` to compile a haskell program, and I get the following error:

```sh
$ ghc --make main   
Linking main ...
ld: building for macOS, but linking in object file built for iOS Simulator, file 'main.o' for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
`clang' failed in phase `Linker'. (Exit code: 1)
```

Here are some details about my machine:

- macOS Catalina 10.15.7
- Xcode 12.2
- The Xcode developer tools were installed with `xcode-select --install`
- I installed `ghc` with `brew install ghc`

Some other output that might be relevant:

```
$ gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.27)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

If I run `ghc --make main -v`, this is what the output looks like right before it fails (apologies for the long line, not sure how to format this better):

```
clang -o main -fno-common -U__PIC__ -D__PIC__ -Wl,-no_compact_unwind main.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/ghc/8.10.1_2/lib/ghc-8.10.1/base-4.14.0.0 -L/usr/local/Cellar/ghc/8.10.1_2/lib/ghc-8.10.1/integer-gmp-1.0.3.0 -L/usr/local/Cellar/ghc/8.10.1_2/libexec/integer-gmp/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/ghc/8.10.1_2/lib/ghc-8.10.1/ghc-prim-0.6.1 -L/usr/local/Cellar/ghc/8.10.1_2/lib/ghc-8.10.1/rts /var/folders/5j/wwtlv8lx0m5fmhc3hy5w5_000000gp/T/ghc49162_0/ghc_2.o -Wl,-u,_base_GHCziTopHandler_runIO_closure -Wl,-u,_base_GHCziTopHandler_runNonIO_closure -Wl,-u,_ghczmprim_GHCziTuple_Z0T_closure -Wl,-u,_ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_True_closure -Wl,-u,_ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_False_closure -Wl,-u,_base_GHCziPack_unpackCString_closure -Wl,-u,_base_GHCziWeak_runFinalizzerBatch_closure -Wl,-u,_base_GHCziIOziException_stackOverflow_closure -Wl,-u,_base_GHCziIOziException_heapOverflow_closure -Wl,-u,_base_GHCziIOziException_allocationLimitExceeded_closure -Wl,-u,_base_GHCziIOziException_blockedIndefinitelyOnMVar_closure -Wl,-u,_base_GHCziIOziException_blockedIndefinitelyOnSTM_closure -Wl,-u,_base_GHCziIOziException_cannotCompactFunction_closure -Wl,-u,_base_GHCziIOziException_cannotCompactPinned_closure -Wl,-u,_base_GHCziIOziException_cannotCompactMutable_closure -Wl,-u,_base_ControlziExceptionziBase_absentSumFieldError_closure -Wl,-u,_base_ControlziExceptionziBase_nonTermination_closure -Wl,-u,_base_ControlziExceptionziBase_nestedAtomically_closure -Wl,-u,_base_GHCziEventziThread_blockedOnBadFD_closure -Wl,-u,_base_GHCziConcziSync_runSparks_closure -Wl,-u,_base_GHCziConcziIO_ensureIOManagerIsRunning_closure -Wl,-u,_base_GHCziConcziIO_ioManagerCapabilitiesChanged_closure -Wl,-u,_base_GHCziConcziSignal_runHandlersPtr_closure -Wl,-u,_base_GHCziTopHandler_flushStdHandles_closure -Wl,-u,_base_GHCziTopHandler_runMainIO_closure -Wl,-u,_ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Czh_con_info -Wl,-u,_ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Izh_con_info -Wl,-u,_ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Fzh_con_info -Wl,-u,_ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Dzh_con_info -Wl,-u,_ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Wzh_con_info -Wl,-u,_base_GHCziPtr_Ptr_con_info -Wl,-u,_base_GHCziPtr_FunPtr_con_info -Wl,-u,_base_GHCziInt_I8zh_con_info -Wl,-u,_base_GHCziInt_I16zh_con_info -Wl,-u,_base_GHCziInt_I32zh_con_info -Wl,-u,_base_GHCziInt_I64zh_con_info -Wl,-u,_base_GHCziWord_W8zh_con_info -Wl,-u,_base_GHCziWord_W16zh_con_info -Wl,-u,_base_GHCziWord_W32zh_con_info -Wl,-u,_base_GHCziWord_W64zh_con_info -Wl,-u,_base_GHCziStable_StablePtr_con_info -Wl,-u,_hs_atomic_add8 -Wl,-u,_hs_atomic_add16 -Wl,-u,_hs_atomic_add32 -Wl,-u,_hs_atomic_add64 -Wl,-u,_hs_atomic_sub8 -Wl,-u,_hs_atomic_sub16 -Wl,-u,_hs_atomic_sub32 -Wl,-u,_hs_atomic_sub64 -Wl,-u,_hs_atomic_and8 -Wl,-u,_hs_atomic_and16 -Wl,-u,_hs_atomic_and32 -Wl,-u,_hs_atomic_and64 -Wl,-u,_hs_atomic_nand8 -Wl,-u,_hs_atomic_nand16 -Wl,-u,_hs_atomic_nand32 -Wl,-u,_hs_atomic_nand64 -Wl,-u,_hs_atomic_or8 -Wl,-u,_hs_atomic_or16 -Wl,-u,_hs_atomic_or32 -Wl,-u,_hs_atomic_or64 -Wl,-u,_hs_atomic_xor8 -Wl,-u,_hs_atomic_xor16 -Wl,-u,_hs_atomic_xor32 -Wl,-u,_hs_atomic_xor64 -Wl,-u,_hs_cmpxchg8 -Wl,-u,_hs_cmpxchg16 -Wl,-u,_hs_cmpxchg32 -Wl,-u,_hs_cmpxchg64 -Wl,-u,_hs_atomicread8 -Wl,-u,_hs_atomicread16 -Wl,-u,_hs_atomicread32 -Wl,-u,_hs_atomicread64 -Wl,-u,_hs_atomicwrite8 -Wl,-u,_hs_atomicwrite16 -Wl,-u,_hs_atomicwrite32 -Wl,-u,_hs_atomicwrite64 -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-dead_strip -lHSbase-4.14.0.0 -lHSinteger-gmp-1.0.3.0 -lHSghc-prim-0.6.1 -lHSrts -lCffi -liconv -lgmp -lm -ldl -Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs
ld: building for macOS, but linking in object file built for iOS Simulator, file 'main.o' for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Curious. — Note that many (most?) Haskellers nowadays never bother with distro- (like Homebrew) -provided GHC, but instead use Stack for everything. Might be worth just going that route too.

Comment: Thanks @leftaroundabout. I tried using stack and was able to build and run a haskell program using `stack new` and then `stack build`. However, `stack new` creates a lot of extra files, and I'm wondering if I can use stack to just compile a single lil' `.hs` file?

Edit: Never mind. I was able to use `stack ghc` to compile a single `.hs` file!